# How to handle a negative test-case in which server is not SSL/TLS enabled but client is SSL/TLS enabled in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, tcp, handshake

I am having a client which is SSL enabled but not my server.

**Background**: So what i am trying to do is,

ClientSide:

1. Client Tries to connect to server
2. Tries to write into the stream
3. Reads data written by server
4. closes conn

ServerSide:

1. Server Accepts TCP Connection
2. Tries Reading data written by client into the stream
3. Writes Reply back to Client
4. Closes Conn

What actually happens is,
Server starts listening on port, and then client just connects to server before the handshake coming to picture.

connects to server means, client side the following is executed

```
SSLSocket sock = (SSLSocket)sslsocketfactory.createSocket(remoteAddress, port);
```

and server accepts using,

```
ServerSocket.accept();
```

i/e ClientSide and ServerSide step 1> completed

Till now the handshake isn't triggered.

Now when client tries to write to stream, prior to that handshake triggers.

i.e Client has now entered into step 2> and server too for reading data.

I analysed packets in WireShark and Client sends the *Client Hello*.
Now as server isn't SSL enabled, it is stuck/stalled at reading data from client and Client is stuck because its waiting for *Server Hello* message.

Eventually both side timeout but how should it be handled actually.

Answer (score 0):

> Eventually both side timeout but how should it be handled actually.

Given that the client does not know that the server does not speak TLS there is no better way for the client than timing out after a while if the server does not respond. The server instead might try to check early if the data sent by the client belong to the expected protocol. This is possible for HTTP since the first few bytes of a ClientHello look totally different from the start of a valid HTTP request. Similar heuristics might be possible for other application protocols too but not for all.

Comment: @MandarA: TCP is not an application protocol, HTTP is. TCP just means transferring a byte stream with no inherent meaning and structure - this meaning is only at the application level. If all you know is "TCP" and nothing about the specific application protocol on top of it then the only way to deal with this case is timeout in the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is attempting to start an SSL handshake over TCP socket. This is fine if you want a secure TCP connection that uses SSL (certificates and cipher suites). BUT you need to also have a server that knows how to communicate in SSL. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket.html).

Basically your server is a "naked" TCP server that knows nothing about SSL. So when your SSL client tries to make a connection to the server, it starts the normal SSL handshake (Client sends hello with cipher suites). Server receives this data, but it means nothing special to it, so it doesn't respond how a SSL server should (Server responds hello with its own cipher suite plus its certificate). Thus as the client waits for that response, it eventually times out.

**SOLUTION**
Either change your server to the SSLSocketServer linked above(the choice if you want a secure SSL connection and have a certificate) or change the client to a normal socket [client](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html)

Comment: Or, have your "plain TCP" server peek the first few bytes and if an SSL/TLS handshake is detected than close the connection immediately.